# Bourbon Neat - Full width outer-container with not gutter

Tags: css, sass, grid, bourbon, neat

**Hello,**

I'm playing around with [Bourbon Neat](http://thoughtbot.github.io/neat-docs/latest/#omega), and I am trying to do three columns which cover the 100% of the windows width outside the configured grid `($max-width: em(1160)`), and without any gutter. Similar to the following image (blue, yellow and green boxes).

[image]

So, to make the full width of the section, I don't specify any 'outer-container' and for remove the gutter I add the mixin 'omega' but looks like this:

[image]

I quick fix I thought myself is adding `width: calc(100% / 3)` to the three articles but I think is not the best solution...

Any idea?

Here I'm leaving the code: [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/andresgl/pen/WxvWzP)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I do think your `width: calc(100% / 3);` was just about the right solution. I came across this exact situation in my work today. @mike-harrison's solution is what I tried first, but as I mentioned there, the `span-columns` mixin makes the `:last-child` smaller than the others. Issues in Github about that were answered that it was very intentional and your use case is better served with simple percentages.

So here's my solution: http://codepen.io/alexbea/pen/BzozXw;

The key rules are:

```
section.HomeProducts
  +row

  article
    float: left
    // width: percentage(1 / 3)
    width: calc(100% / 3)
```

I used your solution with `calc()`, which works, though I also included a commented out approach of `width: percentage(1 / 3)`. Most modern browsers do support `calc()`, but the other would serve older browsers a bit better, I think. The float should take care of any browser variations and is also what Neat uses in the `span-columns` mixin.

I also included the `row()` mixin on the parent to clearfix the whole section and make sure the floating doesn't make them disappear.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it would be to have a 100% `outer-container`, and then use `block-collapse` on the elements inside. I have done a quick pen here:

http://codepen.io/mikehdesign/pen/ZObEdw

HTML is the same as yours, this is my SCSS:

```
section.HomeProducts {
  @include outer-container(100%);

  article {
    @include span-columns(4, block-collapse);
    height: 200px;
    background: green;

    &:first-child {
      background: blue;
    }

    &:nth-child(2) {
      background: yellow;
    }

    &:nth-child(3){
      background: green;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good use case for `block-collapse`. I was actually dealing with just today. The third column will be a bit thinner than the other two due to its status as `:last-child`.

Comment: Ah yes well spotted - I should have checked this before posting. Your solution looks like the best one

Comment: I did the exact same thing just this week, really wanting `span-columns` to do the trick since it seemed the "right way." It's one place where the documentation could be a bit clearer.